# How to add the name of the rows in Pentaho ?

Tags: csv, pentaho

I have a csv file : 
paul , 12/11/65 , 52
sophie , 15/05/94 , 32

I want to have :

name , date , number
paul , 12/11/65 , 52
sophie , 15/05/94 , 32

How could l do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your talking about PDI (Pentaho Data Integration), and further assuming you are using a "Text file output" step, you would need to make sure Header is enabled in the Content tab:
[image]

And then set the fields you want to appear in the resulting text file under the "Fields" tab:

[image]

Make sure you change the Separator (under the Content tab) to a comma if you need to as well.

Comment: If you need to do this dynamically, and pull the field names from the previous steps, you'll need to read up on https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/6.1/0L0/0Y0/0K0/ETL_Metadata_Injection Metadata Injection.